# How would I prove that nondeterministic Turing machines are undecidable?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability, proof-techniques, nondeterminism

How would I go about proving that the language:

$$A_{NTM }= \{\langle N, w\rangle | N \text{ is a nondeterministic TM and } N \text{ accepts }w\}$$

is undecidable?

I looked at the proof for $A_{TM}$ being undecidable, but am struggling to figure out how to prove the above. Any ideas?

Comment: I assume $A_{TM}$ is the language of all Turing Machine-input pars $\langle T, w \rangle$. In that case it suffices to observe that the decidability of $A_{NTM}$ would imply the decidability of $A_{TM}$. Taking contrapositive of the implication (and noticing, as you point out, that $A_{TM}$ is undecidable) shows that  $A_{NTM}$ is also undecidable.

Comment: @Steven Thanks! I suppose that I'm still confused about this part of your comment:

"In that case it suffices to observe that the decidability of $A_{NTM}$ would imply the decidability of $A_{TM}$." 

How does the decidability of $A_{NTM}$ imply the decidability of $A_{TM}$?

Comment: Every deterministic Turing machine is also a (special) non-deterministic Turing machine. Therefore $A_{TM} \subset A_{NTM}$.

Comment: @Steven Maybe I'm missing something but if $L_1 \subset L_2$ and $L_2$ is decidable, then $L_1$ is not necessarily decidable.

Comment: @pblass. What you write is right in general, but in this particular case the decidability of $A_{NTM}$ does imply the decidability of $A_{TM}$ (for a reasonable encoding of the Turing machines). If you have a Turing machine $M$ that decides $A_{NTM}$, and you with to check whether $\langle T,w \rangle \in A_{TM}$, you can use $M$ to check whether $\langle T,w \rangle \in A_{NTM}$. Since $A_{TM} \subset A_{NTM}$, if $M$ rejects you can also reject. If $M$ accepts it suffices to check that $T$ encodes a valid *deterministc* Turing machine. If this is the case, accept. Otherwise reject.

Comment: @Steven Okay, got it. Thank you for the clarification.